# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass error in comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined

In my application is a blog, and under post you can write comment.
My problem is when i want delete the comment show this error.

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

How to fix this problem?

comment_controller :

```html
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  

  def create
    @link = Link.find(params[:link_id])
    @comment = @link.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
     
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'comment was successfully create'}
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.'}
      format.json {head :no_content}
    end
  end

  private
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:link_id, :body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

after try to delete comment log this in terminal:

```html
Started GET "/comments" for ::1 at 2015-02-28 11:52:51 +0330
Processing by CommentsController#index as HTML
  Rendered comments/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    13:   </thead>
    14: 
    15:   <tbody>
    16:     <% @comment.each do |comment| %>
    17:       <tr>
    18:         <td><%= comment.body %></td>
    19:         <td><%= comment.user %></td>
  app/views/comments/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_comments_index_html_erb__2236689348233653025_70351465687200'


  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (8.9ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (26.2ms)
```

Comment index.html.erb

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Comments</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.body %></td>
        <td><%= comment.user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', comment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %>
```

Comment: Could you please provide backtrace for your exception? Seems like this exception can be inside `before_destroy` or `after_destroy` callbacks in `Comment` model.

Comment: I did not notice !! can you more Explain? in my model Comment only this code : 'belongs_to :post'

Comment: Please provide all exception logs from terminal

Comment: Include your index action in the code

Answer (score 0):

I guess, It should be, Please cross check

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
```

Controller Code

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def destroy
    post = Post.where(id: params[:post_id]).take
    post.comments.find(params[:id]).destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to post_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.'}
      format.json {head :no_content}
    end
 end
```

Try this

Comment: @SajadAbedi try write this in your controller

Comment: I'm add this code , but after try delete comment redirect me to page comments !! i want to stay in post view page.

Comment: see my edits, you need to send post_id in destory action, and please read ruby on rails guide